# MySQL/C++ and Prepared Statements: setInt always 0

Tags: c++, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using the MySQL Connector/C++ library to insert values into a database table.  I'm following the examples at

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html

almost exactly.  However, I can't seem to get prepared statements to work with value placeholders.

```
  sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::Instance();

  boost::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> conn(driver->connect("localhost", "", ""));
  conn->setSchema("TESTDB");

  boost::shared_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(conn->createStatement());
  stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TESTTBL");
  stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE TESTTBL (m_id INT)");

  boost::shared_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> pstmt(conn->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TESTTBL VALUES(?)"));
  for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    pstmt->setInt(1, i);
    pstmt->executeUpdate();     // Always inserts 0.
  }
```

Any ideas on why I can't bind to the prepared statement?  The other set* functions have the same result (e.g. if I use setString I get a string '0' in the resulting row).

Comment: When you say it "always inserts 0" do you mean you get ten rows of zero in the database?

Comment: Yes, I get 10 rows of zero, no matter what I pass to setInt().  If I hardcode a number instead of '?' all is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recompiling the C++ connector from source fixed this problem.

Probably a compiler setting in their pre-built binary that didn't agree with my project.  I will talk to MySQL about this.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done SQL in a while, but I think you're forgetting to put the column name there.  The syntax should be:

```
INSERT INTO TESTTBL (column_name) VALUES (?)
```

If you wanted to insert into multiple columns, you'd use comma delimiters:

```
INSERT INTO TESTTBL (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Comment: It's not a syntax issue.  Hardcoding an integer in place of the ? and then skipping the call to setInt works fine.